# Filter input of `contenteditable` html table cells

Tags: javascript, html

I have table cells that are editable:

```
<table>
  <tr> <td contenteditable></td> </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way to only allow one-digit numbers (maybe with a regex?) as input.

I want to validate the content while typing rather than validating it after the input.

PS: I prefer a solution without jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Tables are for display.  For HTML input, generally you would use a Form with an input control.  You can use this to restrict to a one-digit number. When you submit the form with say "888" it will display a message and cancel the form submission.

```
<form action="www.yahoo.com">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="9" >
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: In my case, a table would be much more convenient for formatting purposes. However I try to change the table to a formular. Thank you for your answer.